# How to add background image to bootstrap cards so it would show when hovering?

Tags: html, css, hover

i'm trying to add a background image in the bootstrap card so when I hover the background takes over the card body but still shows the texts above the image.

My css code

```css
.card-img-top:hover {
    transform: scale(1);
    width: 222px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3  mt-5">
        <div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./images/dummy.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                    the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <p><span style=" color: #ffac33;">
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star-half"></i>
                    </span> 4.6 <span class="rate">(19.730)</span></p>
                <h6 class="lineThroughText">10.99$</h6>
                <h5 class="price">10.99$</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the css background rule? You could set it on either element with class `card` or `card-body`.

`.card:hover { background: url("./images/dummy.jpg"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this one. For this - take your image after the texts **.card** div. Make your image class position: absolute and display none. After hovering on **.card** div, display will be **block**. Finally, the z-index on texts will be greater than the image.

Code below-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .card-img-top{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    display:none;
  }
  .card:hover .card-img-top{
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  .card-body{
    z-index: 9999;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3  mt-5">
        <div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
            
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                    the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <p><span style=" color: #ffac33;">
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star-half"></i>
                    </span> 4.6 <span class="rate">(19.730)</span></p>
                <h6 class="lineThroughText">10.99$</h6>
                <h5 class="price">10.99$</h5>
            </div>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Animals/Tigers/tigers-138a.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Another way -**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  
  .card:hover .card-img-overlay{
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  .card-img-overlay{
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3  mt-5">
        <div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
            
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                    the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <p><span style=" color: #ffac33;">
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star-half"></i>
                    </span> 4.6 <span class="rate">(19.730)</span></p>
                <h6 class="lineThroughText">10.99$</h6>
                <h5 class="price">10.99$</h5>
            </div>
            <img class="img-fluid card-img-overlay" src="https://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Animals/Tigers/tigers-138a.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```